# Google Sheets ArrayFormula with Sumifs

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs, array-formulas

Usually don't need help with sheets but I think my brain is imploding from thinking on this too much.

Trying to fill an entire column with an array formula that sums values from a separate column based on conditions from two other columns. If that sounds strange just check out [this example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MPM-yLccOudcAJWji5MBllEPJyCPfJNwvEgPjBT930k/edit#gid=0).

[image: screenshot]

Invoices have numbers. Customer payments have "Into" bank accounts and also invoice numbers associated with them so I know which payment corresponds to which invoice. Sometimes payments are made in pieces. I would like to sum all payments for each invoice and on separate accounts. I know how to do this using sumifs. The trick I want to pull is doing this with one array formula in the first cell. Appreciate all help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The solution that I ended up using was this:

Credit due to 2n9 from google forums. Here is the [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/OrriYjusT6k/2XSeq1FhH3oJ)

`=arrayformula(sumif(B3:B8&C3:C8,F3:F8&"A",A3:A8))`

There were some other very good answers there using queries from Jean-Pierre Verhulst:

`=query(A2:C8, "select B, sum(A) group by B pivot C")`

`=query(query(A2:C8, "select B, sum(A) group by B pivot C"), "select Col2, Col3")`

`=ArrayFormula(query(query(A2:C8, "select B, sum(A) group by B pivot C"), "select Col2, Col3 offset 1",0)+0)`

Each of these solutions solves the problem but in a different way. They have different attributes such as removing headers or choosing only a certain column. Use the link to the google forum for more information.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Query is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, your `SUMIFS` formula works well in a `MAP` function, as shown below:

[image]

The `MAP` function works like a loop in the company invoices, executing a custom function `LAMBDA` for each invoice. Your `SUMIFS` formula is the body of this custom function and requires a minor change to work properly: its criteria `F8`, related to the invoice filter, need to be replaced by the invoice input parameter from the lambda, which I named `invoice`.

Last, but not least, the `MAP` function itself applies for the entire column of invoices, even on blank cells. To avoid this behaviour, wrap the column reference in an `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` function and set the desired number of rows and columns to be evaluated. In this case, it's a single column, and the number of rows can be calculated using a `COUNTA` function on the entire invoices column.

The formula shown in the image does everything explained above.

Comment: Brings me back to my old life to see this question answered! I haven't heard of MAP I'm gonna check that out for curiosity's sake cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have added a column to combine the two conditions that need to match in both tables.

I used an arrayformula to extend the combined conditions, then I used a sumif inside of another arrayformula to do what would have effectively been sumifs within an arrayformula.

Table 1 (Paint Estimate)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(E2:E<>"",E2:E&"First Coat",0),"E"))
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUMIF(Progress!B2:B,T2:T,Progress!G2:G),0))
```

Table 2 (Progress)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A&E2:E)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use SUMIFS to return an array, e.g. in L3

> =SUMIFS(A3:A8,B3:B8,F3:F8,C3:C8,"A")

Note that where a single criteria is normally expected I have used F3:F8, so the formula returns the required array of 6 values

Untested as I'm currently on my ipad and it doesn't seem to like google docs....

Comment: Thanks, but that is my current solution, and so you are correct (forgetting the $ signs though). The formula must be dragged down to apply to all cells. When dealing with new rows every day this is not sustainable. Current formula: `=SUMIFS($A$3:$A$8,$B$3:$B$8,$F$3:$F$8,$C$3:$C$8,"A")`

Comment: Are you actually trying to do this in Excel or google docs? In Excel I'd suggest using a table - with a table the formulas are automatically populated to new rows, no dragging required - so you just use whole columns for the ranges and it works however many rows you have. I'm not sure that functionality is available in google though

Comment: I am using google sheets. I posted as well on the google products forum and some useful answers were proposed. I will answer my own question. Sounds like a good option for excel but I ditched excel years ago, the collaboration and cloud storage are just too important.